# VC8 to VC10 - LNK2005 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 and used CMake to generate the solution files for my project. This process had previously worked fine on VS2005.

The first issue I encountered was because of the new "move constructors", so I had to remove some implicit conversions from my code — fair enough, that works now.

My current situation is as follows: I am compiling **DLL 1**, which is dependent only on some system libraries (Kernel32, etc) **and the CRT**, and **DLL 2**, which links to **DLL 1**, as well as some third party libraries.

The errors I get are along the lines of:

```
DLL1.lib(DLL1.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in objFromDLL2.obj
```

This appears to be exactly the problem described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/75871e7c-1a1e-4e5e-b9c7-4ab40a76d8b0/).

However, nothing in this thread solves my problem.

- I have confirmed that both DLL1 and DLL2 are compiled with the /MD Code Generation flag,
- DLL2 links to squish, glew, and devil — I have manually recompiled all of these *and any libraries they depend on* for VC10, also with /MD
- **edit** As per [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/191de00a-53c9-4bd9-9cb6-e844eb224ca2) (which is similar to my problem), I have removed any instances of classes deriving from std:: containers
- **edit** I have confirmed this is not a 3rd party issue, as I have compiled another project successfully using the same set of libraries, however I still cannot compile my original project
- **edit** dllexport is being used in all required places in my code

What am I missing? Please let me know if I need to provide more information and I will edit the question as best I can.

*update:* It's been a while and I still have no solution. I've been updating the question with responses to comments, and I'm currently working on a different codebase which does work - I'm starting to think that the backwards compatibility for older code has finally started to dry up, and I should just move on.

*more update:* I've found what's probably a very undesirable linker flag, /FORCE:MULTIPLE, which turns the errors into warnings by ignoring all but the first definition of the symbols. There must be bad side-effects of doing this. A test of this flag highlighted an LNK2001: unresolved std::string::npos, which was buried in all the previous LNK2005 errors. The torment never ends.

Comment: Are you sure that none of the third party libraries link with _other_ libraries?

Comment: @dauphic Devil uses many other libraries, which I also compiled with VC10. Question edited to highlight this.

Comment: My initial guess is that the libraries that Devil links with different libraries using different CRT linkage; alternatively, you accidentally built one of the libraries in debug.

Comment: This is probably a useless comment, but I'm wondering if you made sure that your classes and functions are all using dllexport? I've had errors similar to that when I wasn't using it properly.

Comment: It's NOT the problem you link to. That's an undefined symbol; yours is defined twice. The correct number of definitions is of course 1, but a missing symbol is generally a greater problem (duplicate definitions are far easier to merge)

Comment: @MSalters Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Where do undefined symbols come into this?

Comment: Ah sorry, I followed another link on that page and ended up at [this Connect Page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562448/std-string-npos-lnk2001-when-inheriting-a-dll-class-from-std-string#details). But that's LNK2001, not LNK2005.

Comment: /FORCE:MULTIPLE is wrong and hiding a real problem. Can you post a full build log where the link step was done with /VERBOSE set?

Comment: Due to time constraints I have moved on to using a more uptodate version of the codebase with much legacy code stripped out. This has solved all my problems, as it compiles fine with no linker hackery. There must have been stuff in the countless VC6 compatibility classes that has now been removed (we don't use VC6 anymore) which was making VC10 throw a fit. Not to mention VC6's, let's say, slack compiling rules that let you get away with stuff that even VC8 complains about. I'm unsure what to do with this question now, as I don't think it's answerable anymore...

Comment: @badgerr Is _DEBUG defined in your projects?

Answer (score 2):

I have used `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` successfully. It is sometimes inevitable when using a mixed bag of libraries. As long as the linker uses the one & same address to consistently resolve the reference, it works. The other definitions are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to think that your stated assumptions are incorrect. In particular, "DLL 1, which is dependent only on some system libraries (Kernel32, etc)" can't be right if it's compiled with /MD and refers to `std::string::~string`. That would obviously cause a dependency on the CRT.

Aslo, if DLL1 doesn't depend on DLL2, how in the world is the linker aware of files from DLL2?! Have you managed to set up a cyclic dependency by any chance?

Between VS2008 and VS2010, it seems that `std::string::~string` was removed from the CRT. Therefore, it's no longer a DLLimport for your own code. That could explain the difference in behavior. A cyclic dependency between DLL1 and DLL2 wouldn't have mattered to `std::string::~string` since both would get it from the CRT, and that obviously wouldn't be part of the cycle.

Comment: You are correct about the CRT dependency of DLL1 - I unwisely grouped it in as "standard" during my description. DLL2 links against DLL1, that dependency is one-way, as DLL1 does not require DLL2, but DLL2 does require DLL1. The linker is aware of the files from DLL2 because it's DLL2 that i'm compiling/linking, which is then spitting out the LNK2005 errors.

Comment: Ah, right. Hadn't understood what you were linking; I took the "DLL1.lib(DLL1.dll) " as the project being linked.

Comment: No, the linker shows that as the source of the multiply-defined symbol, but I am actually in the linker stage for DLL2. Interesting point about the removal of ~string though, I might look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that DLL1 does export `std::string` (probably implicitly, because it's used in a class that's also exported), but the headers of DLL1 don't declare that. Therefore, when DLL2 is compiled, it's not noted as an import. This is no problem, because it's a template: the compiler just instantiates another copy. But then the linker stumbles, because DLL2 really should have imported `std::string`.

Solution: explicitly export/import `std::string`; you probably already have an appropriate macro for the `_declspec( )` in your DLL1 header(s).

Comment: I followed [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958) and get the expected C4231 warnings, but LNK2005 persists. Did I do it wrong? EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template DECLSPECIFIER std::string;